# maven junit.framework does not exist

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit

I am new to maven.
I was using IntelliJ and want to create a maven quickstart project.

My pom is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.travisprogramming.spring.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>testprog</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>testprog</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The java file is under src, and I got errors like this:

> Error:(3, 23) java: package junit.framework does not exist
>     Error:(4, 23) java: package junit.framework does not exist
>     Error:(5, 23) java: package junit.framework does not exist
>     Error:(11, 13) java: cannot find symbol
>          symbol: class TestCase
>     Error:(26, 19) java: cannot find symbol
>            symbol:   class Test
>     location: class com.travisprogramming.spring.test.AppTest

I tried deleting the `<scope>test</scope>` it didn't work.

I tried creating a new java file under the test, and run that file, it got same errors.

[image: root]

Comment: right click on `pom.xml`, `Maven` -> `Reimport`

Comment: Are you trying to run the @test class from the package `src>main>java`? Your @test classes should be under `src>test>java` and not in the `src>main>java`.

Comment: 1. I suppose you imported the Maven project into IntelliJ properly, and do you see your declared junit dependency in External Libraries of IntelliJ's project view?  2. Does it works for maven command line build? 3. Are you really sure you want to use JUnit 3 given that JUnit 4 and even 5 has been around for quite a long time?

Comment: Use JUnit 4 which means JUnit 4.12 etc.

Comment: I tried reimport maven and it works. Thanks！

Answer (score 0):

The possible cause for this problem could be problems while importing your project in IntelliJ. Try re-importing the pom. Also ensure that you have appropriate directory structure for Test and Application source files.

- Application Source should be in  - src > main > java
- Test source
  should be in - src > test > java

If that still doesn't work, try compiling project through command line using `mvn compile` and check if there are any problems while downloading artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you installed the Maven Integration plugin.
2. Reimport the Project again and try to make default for enabling auto import which is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you are declared it as `<scope>test</scope>`

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

So junit will be available `src/test/java` so do not use the scope if you not make sure your codes are not in `src/test/java` packages

if it is not works then delete all your files in `~/.m2/repository` and run `mvn clean -X install` you will get detailed logs